# .corr() method for dataframe not returning ideal values only returns either -1 or 1

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, pearson-correlation

Ideally it should be returning values between -1 and 1 for every cell except for the cells that have the same column name and row name those need to have a 1 value

Tried replacing the NaN with 0 before doing corr() and it returns proper values but those values are inaccurate for the purpose of the program

```
# df
            MovieA    MovieB    MovieC    MovieD  MovieE
Angee     0.000000       NaN -0.500000  0.500000     NaN
Anirvesh  1.166667 -0.333333 -0.833333       NaN     NaN
Jay       1.166667 -0.333333       NaN -0.833333     NaN
Karthik   0.000000 -1.500000       NaN       NaN     1.5
Naman          NaN  0.250000       NaN -0.250000     NaN

# df.T.corr()
          Angee  Anirvesh  Jay  Karthik  Naman
Angee       1.0       1.0 -1.0      NaN    NaN
Anirvesh    1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    NaN
Jay        -1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    1.0
Karthik     NaN       1.0  1.0      1.0    NaN
Naman       NaN       NaN  1.0      NaN    1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NaNs are correct, they are returned when you cannot compute the correlation because of NaNs. This happens when you don't have at least **two** common values.

Filling the NaNs **before** computation indeed doesn't make sense as this will add fake datapoints that will be used to compute the correlation.

What you could do is [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `0` **after** the computation if you really don't want NaNs:

```
out = df.T.corr().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
          Angee  Anirvesh  Jay  Karthik  Naman
Angee       1.0       1.0 -1.0      0.0    0.0
Anirvesh    1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    0.0
Jay        -1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    1.0
Karthik     0.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    0.0
Naman       0.0       0.0  1.0      0.0    1.0
```

Comment: Also, no pair of users has **more** than 2 common values. If there are exactly 2 common values, then the correlation must be +1 or -1 (you can draw a straight line that exactly fits the values). So every element of the output is +1 or -1 or NaN.

Comment: @slothrop yes, that's a very valid point

Answer (score 0):

Although your requirement is quite vague, you can still look at this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'MovieA': [0, 1.166667, 1.166667, 0, np.nan],
                   'MovieB': [np.nan, -0.333333, -0.333333, -1.5, 0.25],
                   'MovieC': [-0.5, -0.833333, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'MovieD': [0.5, np.nan, -0.833333, np.nan, -0.25],
                   'MovieE': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1.5, np.nan]},
                  index=['Angee', 'Anirvesh', 'Jay', 'Karthik', 'Naman'])
"""
print(df)
            MovieA    MovieB    MovieC    MovieD  MovieE
Angee     0.000000       NaN -0.500000  0.500000     NaN
Anirvesh  1.166667 -0.333333 -0.833333       NaN     NaN
Jay       1.166667 -0.333333       NaN -0.833333     NaN
Karthik   0.000000 -1.500000       NaN       NaN     1.5
Naman          NaN  0.250000       NaN -0.250000     NaN
"""

# Calculate correlations with Pearson's method
corr_matrix = df.T.corr(method='pearson')
"""print(corr_matrix)
          Angee  Anirvesh  Jay  Karthik  Naman
Angee       1.0       1.0 -1.0      NaN    NaN
Anirvesh    1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    NaN
Jay        -1.0       1.0  1.0      1.0    1.0
Karthik     NaN       1.0  1.0      1.0    NaN
Naman       NaN       NaN  1.0      NaN    1.0
"""
# Fill diagonal with let's say 999.Just for understanding.
np.fill_diagonal(corr_matrix.values, 999)

"""
print(corr_matrix)
          Angee  Anirvesh    Jay  Karthik  Naman
Angee     999.0       1.0   -1.0      NaN    NaN
Anirvesh    1.0     999.0    1.0      1.0    NaN
Jay        -1.0       1.0  999.0      1.0    1.0
Karthik     NaN       1.0    1.0    999.0    NaN
Naman       NaN       NaN    1.0      NaN  999.0"""


# Concise Filling diagonal with let's say 888.Just for understanding.Also adding fillna(0)
corr_matrix = df.T.corr(method='pearson').where(~np.eye(len(df), dtype=bool), 888).fillna(0)
"""print(corr_matrix)

          Angee  Anirvesh    Jay  Karthik  Naman
Angee     888.0       1.0   -1.0      0.0    0.0
Anirvesh    1.0     888.0    1.0      1.0    0.0
Jay        -1.0       1.0  888.0      1.0    1.0
Karthik     0.0       1.0    1.0    888.0    0.0
Naman       0.0       0.0    1.0      0.0  888.0
"""
```